# Creating custom mailbox in outlook without using the mail protocols

Tags: email, outlook, customization, outlook-addin

I want to create a custom mailbox that is consisted of the mail default folders like inbox, send, etc without using the mail protocols like IMAP or POP. I also want this mailbox to work with my database using some APIs that I have developed on the back-end. for example when I click on Inbox folder I want outlook to call my specific API to fetch my inbox items. 
Is this possible or not? if it is which APIs or technology should I use?

Any suggestions for my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the reply at the Outlook Dev forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/ad9dc25a-da58-4b51-b480-c38c9b1f684c